# react multiple state const for jsx

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I want to render jsx as just an input field when isEditingAll is set true, where a parent component could set this to true. But I also want the component itself to have the ability to save data individually. So when isEditing is true, I am also rendering the same input field. I have the following code:

```
return(
    <span className="displayList ">
        <div className="flex-label"><label className="flex-label-size">Author: </label>
        {this.state.isEditingAll ?
            <span className="flex-label-size"><input name="inputValue" className="inputValue" value={this.state.value} type="text" onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress} onChange={this.onTextChanged}/></span>
            :
            this.state.isEditing ? '' : <span className="clickMe flex-label-size" onClick={this.onClickEdit}>{this.state.value}</span> &&
            this.state.isEditing ? <span className="flex-label-size"><input name="inputValue" className="inputValue" value={this.state.value} type="text" onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress} onChange={this.onTextChanged}/></span> : ''&&
            this.state.isEditing ? <button className="saveMe" onClick={this.onSaveEdit}>Save</button> :''
        }
        </div>
    </span>
)
```

My input field is duplicated twice, is there anyway to use a const outside of the return to pass in the input to use it multiple times and only use the jsx once?

Comment: Can you better clarify what you want to display for each of the combinations of `isEditingAll` and `isEditing` respectively are: (1) `true` and `true`, (2) `true` and `false`, (3) `false` and `true`, (4) `false` and `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid using tertiary operators like this.  Your code is incredibly difficult to read because of these chained methods, and the cause of your bug is due to how those tertiary operators combine.  Instead of fixing the bug, you should just refactor to avoid the needless confusion;

Instead, just make an access method:

```
getInputField() {
    if ( this.props.isEditingAll || this.state.isEditing ) {
        return <span className="flex-label-size"><input name="inputValue" className="inputValue" value={this.state.value} type="text" onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress} onChange={this.onTextChanged}/></span>
    }
}
```

And then call within your render function simply with:

```
{this.getInputField()}
```

Comment: that is good for that field, but then I need it to be combined with the save button, only when isEditing is true. How do I combine that too?

Comment: Create a second accessor function `getSaveButton`.  Update the conditional and return values accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a good way to do that.

**Example** (setting a const with a input field):

```
render() {
    const inputField = (<input name="inputValue" className="inputValue" value={this.state.value} type="text" onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress} onChange={this.onTextChanged}/>);
    return(
        <span className="displayList ">
            <div className="flex-label"><label className="flex-label-size">Author: </label>
            {this.state.isEditingAll ? (
              <span className="flex-label-size"><input name="inputValue" className="inputValue" value={this.state.value} type="text" onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress} onChange={this.onTextChanged}/></span>
            ) : (
              this.state.isEditing ? '' : <span className="clickMe flex-label-size" onClick={this.onClickEdit}>{this.state.value}</span> &&
              this.state.isEditing ? <span className="flex-label-size"> {inputField} </span> : ''&&
              this.state.isEditing ? <button className="saveMe" onClick={this.onSaveEdit}>Save</button> :''
            )}
    </div>
</span>
```

Regards,

Renan